# What CUDA GPU should I buy?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I am new to CUDA and going to buy a GPU that will be sufficient for my needs without spending much. I will be working on an application that will require graphics rendering as well as other general purpose computations.

What should be my primary consideration while buying ?

- No. of SMs
- No. of CUDA Cores
- Core/Shader/Memory Clock
- Memory Size
- Memory Bus width

How do the above mentioned specifications affect CUDA performance?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it is off-topic here.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not the type of question that is a good fit for this site. Please have a look at [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to get an idea of what kind of questions you can ask here.

Comment: This is related to Programming imho. To understand CUDA version, one needs to be able to program and understand what these CUDA versions have to offer. It may not be directly related but it still holds a question to any programmer. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/364274/kingpin

Comment: @KingPIN: I wouldn't say that you are wrong, just that your opinion on this runs against the general tide of opinion here on SO.  Many questions which are related to programming are ruled off-topic.

Comment: @KiNGPiN: It might be peripherally related to CUDA programming, but it isn't a good fit as a question. There is no correct answer - every response would be completely subjective. And whatever answer might be "appropriate now" will be stale and out of date within a month or too. It is for these reasons that "what package/language/hardware/book/course" questions are considered off topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA Start a Depth First Search from there. Vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: Vote to close, dupe of this:  http://forums.developer.nvidia.com/devforum/discussion/6096/what-cuda-gpu-should-i-buy-